# How do I write a csv file in R, where my input is written to the file as row?

Tags: r, csv

This is a very simple issue and I'm surprised that there are no examples online.

I have a vector:

```
vector <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
```

I would like to write this as a csv as a simple row:

```
write.csv(vector, file ="myfile.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

When I open up the file I've just written, the csv is written as a column of values.
It's as if R decided to put in newlines after each number 1.

Forgive me for being ignorant, but I always assumed that the point of having comma-separated-values was to express a sequence from left to right, of values, separated by commas.  Sort of like I just did; in a sense mimicking the syntax of written word.  Why does R cling so desperately to the column format when a csv so clearly should be a row?

All linguistic philosophy aside, I have tried to use the transpose function.  I've dug through the documentation.  Please help!  Thanks.

Comment: Five answers and none of them suggested it: use `cat`.

Comment: Why not propose a sixth answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on what @Matt said, if you want a csv, try `eol=","`.

Answer (score 5):

`write.csv` is designed for matrices, and R treats a single vector as a matrix with a single column.  Try making it into a matrix with one row and multiple columns and it should work as you expect.

```
write.csv(matrix(vector, nrow=1), file ="myfile.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Not sure what you tried with the transpose function, but that should work too.

```
write.csv(t(vector), file ="myfile.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did:

```
cat("myVar <- c(",file="myVars.r.txt", append=TRUE);

cat( myVar,       file="myVars.r.txt", append=TRUE, sep=", ");

cat(")\n",        file="myVars.r.txt", append=TRUE);
```

this generates a text file that can immediately be re-loaded into R another day using:

```
source("myVars.r.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried with this:

```
write.csv(rbind(vector), file ="myfile.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Output is getting written column wise, but, with column names.

This one seems to be better:

```
write.table(rbind(vector), file = "myfile.csv", row.names =FALSE, col.names = FALSE,sep = ",")
```

Now, the output is being printed as:

```
1   1   1   1   1
```

in the .csv file, without column names.

Answer (score 1):

`write.table(vector, "myfile.csv", eol=" ", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)`

You can simply change the eol to whatever you want. Here I've made it a space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cat` to append rows to a file. The following code would write a vector as a line to the file:

```
myVector <- c("a","b","c")
cat(myVector, file="myfile.csv", append = TRUE, sep = ",", eol = "\n")
```

This would produce a file that is comma-separated, but with trailing commas on each line, hence it is not a CSV-file.

If you want a **real CSV-file**, use the solution given by @vamosrafa. The code is as follows:

```
write.table(rbind(myVector), file = "myfile.csv", row.names =FALSE, col.names = FALSE,sep = ",", append = TRUE)
```

The output will be like this:

```
"a","b","c"
```

If the function is called multiple times, it will add lines to the file.

Answer (score 0):

One more:

```
write.table(as.list(vector), file ="myfile.csv", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

fwrite from data.table package is also another option:

```
library(data.table)

vector <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
fwrite(data.frame(t(vector)),file="myfile.csv",sep=",",row.names = FALSE)
```