# R - Reading a horizontally arranged csv file, replacing values and saving again

Tags: r, csv

I have a horizontally arranged CSV [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ukyuifvpq1olqk/samplefile.csv?dl=0) (`samplefile.csv`) with headers are in the first column. Also, each row has a different number of columns. I want to read this CSV file, replace one of the cell value and save again as a CSV file with the same format as the original file with exactly same number of columns and rows. 
It sounds like a simple task, but I am struggling to find a way. I tried to do this with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288197/reading-a-csv-file-organized-horizontally) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308621/how-do-i-write-a-csv-file-in-r-where-my-input-is-written-to-the-file-as-row) posts, but still, I can't get the output the way I want. Can somebody help me here?

**Edit**

my attempt using the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288197/reading-a-csv-file-organized-horizontally) to read the CSV file (`samplefile.csv`) gives me the following output where headers are kinda messed up and empty cells are replaced with NA values which is not what I want

```
aaa <- read.tcsv("samplefile.csv")
aaa

     Header.1 Header.2..units. Header.3..units. Header.3..units..1
1   Some text           0.0625                0             264896
2        <NA>           0.0625             1200             664747
3        <NA>           0.0625             1380                  1
4        <NA>           0.2500             1500                  1
5        <NA>           0.6250             1620                 NA
6        <NA>           1.3125             1740                 NA
7        <NA>           2.4375             1860                 NA
8        <NA>           3.5625             1980                 NA
9        <NA>           4.6250             2100                 NA
10       <NA>           5.0000             2220                 NA
11       <NA>           5.0000             2340                 NA
12       <NA>           4.6250             2460                 NA
13       <NA>           3.5625             2580                 NA
14       <NA>           2.4375             2700                 NA
15       <NA>           1.3125             2820                 NA
16       <NA>           0.6250             2940                 NA
17       <NA>           0.2500             3060                 NA
18       <NA>           0.0625             3180                 NA
19       <NA>           0.0000             3300                 NA
20       <NA>           0.0000            18000                 NA
```

Also, I am not sure how to go back to original format when I save the file again after a modification (for example after replacing a cell value)

I tried saving the file again by using `t` (transpose) as given below

```
write.csv(t(aaa), file ="samplefile_e.csv", row.names=T)
```

but still, there are following issues in the saved file

1. messed up headers
2. empty cells are replaced with `NA`
3. when I open the file in a text editor all the values are shown as characters

Comment: What code did you try exactly? How did your attempts fail? You should include a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in the question itself (don't link to an external dropbox file). Show exactly how you are trying to make a change to the data.

Comment: I added some more details on my attempt. Thanks

Comment: Where does the `read.tcsv` function come from? That's not a base R function. How exactly are you saving the file?

Comment: More details added. The `read.tcsv` function is from the only answer to the post for which I provided the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a solution from Bill Dunlap in R- help mail list.

In his words

*Using read.table to read data with a variable number of entries per row is probably a mistake - data.frames (which read.table returns) are not meant for this sort of data.You want to store the data in R as a list with 
names.*

Complete answer can be found [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-Reading-a-horizontally-arranged-csv-file-replacing-values-and-saving-again-tt4752831.html#a4752886)